# How to Make a JList with "x" Buttons in Each Cell

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, custom-controls

I would like to make a custom component that is much like a JList, except there is a little "x" button on the right side of each cell that removes that cell from the list (and triggers an event). I know that you would have to extend JList, but looking at the code for JList I have no idea where to go from there. For reference, I would like the list to be like on the macOS Messages app (except the "x" button can always be visible, not just when the mouse is over the cell).

[image]

Comment: Do you have an attempt to post? Hopefully in a [mcve]?

Comment: The main problem is that I don't understand the JList code so I don't know where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to make a custom component

I suggest you do that by extending `JPanel` and adding real components to your panel. Then you can actually add `JButton` with the "x" that can respond to the mouse event.

A JList does not display real components, only rendered images of the component and therefore is does not respond to events if you try to click on the "x".

The other option is to use a JTable. A JTable does allow you to display values in a column format. In this case it does support the concept of editors, which would allow you to add a button to a column. For example check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!